# create-react-app .env: process not defined

Tags: reactjs

create-react-app is supposed to inject your `.env` variables into your React app. I have used the `REACT_APP_` prefix with my variables in my `.env` and `.env.development`.

However,  when debugging the code I've found that `process` itself is undefined. So when trying to access an environment variable with `process.env.REACT_APP_SOMETHING_URL`, the root `process` variable is undefined.

Comment: https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d

Comment: How are you checking that `process` is undefined? Take into account that when webpack transpiles your code, it replaces all occurrences of `process.env` with the string value that was given.

Answer (score 14):

So at the time I misunderstood *how* `process.env` works in `create-react-app`. I expected this to be available at runtime. However, because React is a frontend library and `process` is a Node backend entity you cannot directly access `process.env` while executing code in the browser.

This makes sense because in-browser executed Javascript doesn't know about Node; therefore, `process.env` isn't available.

What happens instead is that during a webpack build, webpack will inject the corresponding environment variables into your frontend asset code. So if you have a production `.env` file, those variables are provided during the build.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ yarn add --dev react-app-env
```

or

```
$ npm install react-app-env --save-dev
```

Comment: please format your code with the code tags provided in the editor. this improves readability for everybody

Answer (score 0):

well let me begin by saying `process` is an eventEmitter what lives in the nodejs world if you log it in a browser, no matter if it is angular, CRA, Vue, jquery all of them will print undefined because in the context of a browser it does not exist.

now on a CRA you is able to use `process.env.YOW_VAR`, basically bcuz CRA creates an Obj call `process.env` that is the reason behind why you need to add a prefix to them env vars which I think is REACT_APP.

```js
  
const YOW_VARS = Object.keys(process.env)
    .filter(key => REACT_APP.test(key))
    .reduce(
      (env, key) => {
        env[ key ] = process.env[ key ];
        return env;
      },
      {
        NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
      }
    );

  const s = {
    'process.env': Object.keys(YOW_VARS).reduce((env, key) => {
      env[ key ] = JSON.stringify(YOW_VARS[ key ]);
      return env;
    }, {}),
  };
```

more or less they have something like that

Answer (score 0):

The react-app-env package suggested on another post on this page is deprecated, as described in its repo: https://github.com/tuchk4/react-app-env

I recommend using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using `docusaurus` and getting this issue while they trying to access env variable in there react component, you fix this issue by
installing  [`docusaurus-plugin-dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusaurus-plugin-dotenv) and add this configuration to your `daucusaurus.config.js` file

```json
plugins: 
[
...
    [
      'docusaurus-plugin-dotenv',
      {
          path: "./.env", 
          systemvars: true, 
      }
    ]
....
]
```

Now you can access the env variable in your application without a problem

```js
...
const DOMAIN = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
....
```